# Questions on Psak Halacha

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, contemporary-halacha

If one is learning Halacha and comes across a machlokes between recent Poskim (post Mishna Berura eg is one allowed to make a tea in a Kli Shelishi) can one decide by himself to be meikel if the logic of one of the Poskim resonates with him more. Can sources please be provided.

Furthermore, it is quite common that people will listen to a Halacha shiur by a Rabbi who is not their specific Rav such as a shiur between Mincha/Ma'ariv or online etc about a specific Halachic topic which they may not know too much about. Isn't following the Halacha from such a shiur (without consulting their main Rav) the same as the case above (Not having a specific Rav)  yet many people will do the latter and not the former.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you specifically ask regarding recent poskim? What if there's a machlokes mishnah berurah and aruch hashulchan? Or chayei Adam and Shulchan Aruch harav? Or pri megadim and derech hachaim/chavos daas?

Comment: Obviously if you are qualified to paskin a question you can if you aren't you can't. What are you not sure about?

Comment: I belong to the Ashkenazi community who generally pasken like the Mishna Berura. Thats why I said post MB but theoreticallt the same could be said about a machlokes Taz and Shach in Yoreh Deah

Comment: It is insanely unlikely you will understand the *sugyah* by listening to a *shiur* "on tape".

Comment: I didn't mean a sugya , I meant a point which the Poskim argue about eg fishing on Chol Hamoed (machlokes RMF and RSZA)